# How to loop over the list in the second if

Tags: python, list

I have a list.  I need to pass event['params']['path']['match'] == i

```
event = {'body-json': {}, 'params': {'path': {'match': '%20'}, 'querystring': {}, 'header': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'xx.amazonaws.com', 'Postman-Token': '50ae98db-6077-47c4-ac11-bfc53ac78990', 'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.2', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-5f2cb950-27ff7e6789988bd6b1a74d76', 'X-Forwarded-For': 'xxx.24', 'X-Forwarded-Port': '443', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https'}}, 'stage-variables': {}, 'context': {'account-id': '', 'api-id': 'xx', 'api-key': '', 'authorizer-principal-id': '', 'caller': '', 'cognito-authentication-provider': '', 'cognito-authentication-type': '', 'cognito-identity-id': '', 'cognito-identity-pool-id': '', 'http-method': 'POST', 'stage': 'v1', 'source-ip': 'xx.24', 'user': '', 'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.2', 'user-arn': '', 'request-id': '8d13e523-de12-4527-b58d-b11a7c8d09fb', 'resource-id': 'td4vr4', 'resource-path': '/{match}'}}
```

Code is below

```
list_ = [',' , '.' , '$' , ' ']
for i in list_:
    if bool(event['params']['path'])== False or event['params']['path']['match'] == i:
          print ('test success')
```

Basically I need to loop over the list_

`event['params']['path']['match'] == i`

I don't want to do like below

```
if bool(event['params']['path'])== False or event['params']['path']['match'] == $ \ 
              or event['params']['path']['match'] == .  or event['params']['path']['match'] == , :
              print ('test success')
```

Comment: I suggest you try to explain what you want, what you tried, and what did not work. So far, I see four pieces of invalid Python code and some random words surrounding the,. Your question does not make sense.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if event['params']['path']['match'] in list_` condition

Answer (score 1):

```
list_ = [',' , '.' , '$' , ' ']
for i in list_:
    if bool(event['params']['path'])== False or event['params']['path']['match'] in list_:
          print ('test success')
```